wxWidgets: wxFrame() creation diverges by a few pixel, what am I doing wrong?
I am coming from MFC and are currently about to verify wxWidgets.
The following code compiles under ucrt64 and runs on a Windows 10 system.
My expectation is that the main windows has a size of 250x250px and is positioned at 100,100px.
The actual position on the screen is at 108,100 and the size is 234x242.
This happens only on my two Windows 10 systems, on Windows 7 systems all is fine.
I am quite sure I did a stupid beginner mistake, can somebody enlighten me, please?
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include "ProjectBase.h"

class Application : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(Application);

bool Application::OnInit()
{
    wxWindow *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Test", wxPoint(100, 100), wxSize(250, 250), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wxRESIZE_BORDER);
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

Screenshot:


Applying MoveWindow() to the frame handle doesn't help.
Applying frame->SetSize() doesn't help.
Using a 3rd party program: https://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/ in order to modify my frame externally sets the size exactly to what I am expecting.
The Windows 10 display scale is at 100%.
I tried #define wxUSE_DPI_AWARE_MANIFEST 2 in a resource file without success. (The mechanism works on scaled displays but the deviation stays.)


try without wxRESIZE_BORDER.

Removing wxRESIZE_BORDER doesn't make a diference.

How do you measure the position and the size of the window on screen?

I measure the position using the 3rd party tool https://picpick.ap. It comes with a magnifier, rulers and a crosshair.
